# Combine multiple fonts and randomly choose from them using Geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, random

Combine multiple fonts and randomly choose from them using Geometry nodes

I'm trying to randomly choose from multiple different fonts.  I tried using the join but it seems not to be working as expected. I tried using a transform node on one of the fonts to move things around but that doesn't seem like the best solution if I need to vary the amount of characters or fonts.

[image: img1]

My logic was to combine multiple fonts into one "variable / array / group" then randomly choose characters from that "variable / array / group".  Should I not be using join to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be this kind of setting:

[image]

Where the node group is the following:

[image]

The node group takes the previous text, transforms it into a mesh and gets the max value of its bounding box. Then, it translates the next text from its X value.

[image]